# Generating Static HTML App from a JSP site

Tags: jsp, dojo

I've a Java web app, using JSP+Struts2+Spring and Dojox.mobile. Is there any best practice to turn the web app into a static html app ? I've to package it at the end into a PhoneGap application which must run offline.

I also had a look at iJetty but we have to many libs.

Any hint is welcome. Thank you guys, 
Guenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try HTTrack Website Copier, it will crawl the website and download it, so it's available for offline browsing

http://www.httrack.com/

Comment: Hi,thanks but I guess httrack will not parse my script actions. I am loading a lot new pages by Dojo's xhr.

Comment: well, maybe you will need to make requested pages via XHR static first so the requests would be resolved correctly offline.

Comment: Well, thanks again. I am looking into i-Jetty servlets for Android.